# How to set objects as form values in react with Material UI?

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, material-ui, react-forms

I'm currently trying to build a form with React and Material UI, where my final payload has to look like this:

```
{
  title: title,
  quadrants: {
    0: { name: quadrantOne },
    1: { name: quadrantTwo },
    2: { name: quadrantThree },
    3: { name: quadrantFour }
  }
}
```

The corresponding part of my form (including initial values) is structured as follows:

```
const initialValues = {
  title: '',
  quadrants: {},
};

const [values, setValues] = useState(initialValues);

const handleInputChange = (e: any) => {
  const { name, value } = e.target;
  setValues({
    ...values,
    [name]: value
  });
};

return (
    <Form>
        <Grid item xs={12} sm={12}>
          <Input
            name="title"
            label="Title"
            value={initialValues.title}
            onChange={handleInputChange}
          />
        </Grid>
        <Grid item xs={12} sm={6}>
          <Input
            name="quadrant-one"
            label="Quadrant 1"
            value={initialValues.quadrants}
            onChange={handleInputChange}
          />
        </Grid>
        <Grid item xs={12} sm={6}>
          <Input
            name="quadrant-two"
            label="Quadrant 2"
            value={initialValues.quadrants}
            onChange={handleInputChange}
          />
        </Grid>
    </Form>
)
```

In this way, my input fields look like this, so that I cannot enter anything in the fields::

[image]

But if I enter something in the fields (the entry is not visible), then I get the following payload:

```
{
  title: "Test"
  quadrants: {}
  quadrant-one: "[object Object]"
  quadrant-two: "[object Object]"
}
```

The entries are not nested in the "quadrants" object, but entries appear in the payload with the name of the respective form element (Like quadrant-one, quadrant-two..).

What am I doing wrong here and how can I fix this?

Comment: You are passing and object as value -->value={initialValues.quadrants}, maybe should be value={initialValues.quadrants[0].name}

Comment: I know that passing an object is wrong. The funny thing is that the quadrants property is an object not an array. So I can't use {initialValues.quadrants[0].name}..

Comment: Yes, you can use initialValues.quadrants[0], try it.

Comment: @lissettdm It says: "TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of undefined" when I use values.quadrants[0].name. Do I need to change the structure of quadrants: {} inside initialValues?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are getting `[Object Object]` because initialValues.quadrants is an object, I assume you are trying to set initialValues.quadrants[0].name, but as initial value initialValues.quadrants[0] is undefined

You need to apply some changes. I recommend you define a custom attribute (data-index) for the quadrants input, this way on input change you can update the correct object. Also for the quadrants inputs you can define a function to get the value because at first render it value is undefined:

```
const initialValues = {
    title: "",
    quadrants: {}
  };

  const [values, setValues] = useState(initialValues);

  const handleInputChange = e => {
    const { name, value } = e.target;
    const dataIndex = Number(e.target.getAttribute("data-index"));
    setValues(prev => {
      if (name === "title") {
        return {
          ...prev,
          [name]: value
        };
      } else {
        return {
          ...prev,
          quadrants: {
            ...prev.quadrants,
            [dataIndex]: { name: value }
          }
        };
      }
    });
  };

  const getValue = prop => {
    const value = values.quadrants[prop] ? values.quadrants[prop].name : "";
    return value;
  };

return (
    <Form>
        <Grid item xs={12} sm={12}>
          <Input
            name="title"
            label="Title"
            value={values.title}
            onChange={handleInputChange}
          />
        </Grid>
        <Grid item xs={12} sm={6}>
          <Input
            name="quadrant-one"
            label="Quadrant 1"
            data-index="0"
            value={getValue(0)}
            onChange={handleInputChange}
          />
        </Grid>
        <Grid item xs={12} sm={6}>
          <Input
            name="quadrant-two"
            label="Quadrant 2"
            data-index="1"
            value={getValue(1)}
            onChange={handleInputChange}
          />
        </Grid>
    </Form>
)
```

Comment: Works! Thank you. Maybe I'll create an own changeHandler for my quadrants, so that I can remove the if within the setValues.

Comment: Yes, I think it is much cleaner to divide handleInputChange function

Answer (score 0):

Try this **fixes**:-

- change `input` `value` from `value={initialValues.title}` to `value={values.title}`. Since you already set your `initialValues` to `state` `values`. The `onChange` event only be reflected on `state` `values` being updated with `setValues`. Not directly on `const initialValues` (do the same for the rest of the **inputs** - only inputs that use `values` `state`)
- `function` to `handleTitleChange()`

```js
const handleTitleChange = (e: any) => {
  const { name, value } = e.target;
  
  setValues({
    ...values,
    [name]: value
  });
};
```

- `function` to `handleQuadrantChange()`

```js
const handleQuadrantChange = (e: any) => {
  const { name, value } = e.target;
  
  setValues({
    ...values,
    quadrants: {
      ...values.quadrants,
      [name]: value
    }
  });
};
```

Comment: Ok, but the question was not related to the use of initialState, but to the setting of object values ​​inside the object quadrants: {}.

Comment: I just update my answer above. Have a try

Comment: Actually, that's exactly what I wanted to avoid. The functions are exactly the same, so they actually repeat themselves. In addition, that doesn't solve my problem either. Like this I can't nest other objects in the quadrants: {} object, as described in my question. Check my needed final payload at the top.